# Why Nginx cuts long responses from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, nginx

When I access Node.js directly (https:// domain.com:81) I get the whole response. When I go through the Nginx (https:// domain.com/eval/something) I don't get the whole response in the case that there is a quite a big response.

Config file

```
location ~ ^/eval/ {
    proxy_buffering    off;
    proxy_pass         https://domain.com:81;
}
```

EDIT:
It returns no more than 16kB. The whole response has over 160kB.

NGINX DEBUG FILE:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4689ch6lonxsqrn/nginx.log

SOLVED:
The problem was with `https://domain.com:81`. If I set only `http://` it works fine.

Comment: Are the response http headers of both urls same?

Comment: The same. HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2013 14:29:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Conection: close

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [`proxy_buffering`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering) on? Maybe node is taking to long to answer and nginx stops reading. Try increasing the [`proxy_read_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) (default is 60s).

Comment: Enable [debug log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html), capture a single request and add the result to your question.

Comment: I have added link to the debug log file to the question.

Comment: You should answer this question with the solution and mark your own answer as the solution to the problem. Otherwise this thread stays open as unanswered.